# Any player in ubuntu 14.04 unable to play hd videos

Tags: video

A HD movie of 1.5 GB size unable to play in any player of ubuntu 14.04. (Players i used to play are SMPLAYER, VLC, DRAGON) even though installed ubutnu restricted extras &  All player are updated to latest versions. Video is in MP4 format with aac audio.

when i open that file in any above players it remain only player opened, but no any error message and no partially playing.

help me how to play those videos.

Comment: We need a lot more info from you than what you've provided. What format is the video encoded in? Do any of the media players give you any error messages? Does the file open and play partially and then close? Does it not open at all? Do you have any codecs installed? etc. All I can suggest right now is that you try installing the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package from the Ubuntu Software Centre, and then rebooting and trying to play the video again.

Comment: Does that file open in another computer? It could be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I can play HD video files (1080) with mkv and mp4 extension by using XBMC Media Center on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 but I have my own computer that differs with yours. And even I can watch those file which are for 5.1 speakers with DOLBY quality by that software. But I am not sure about you and your computer. Maybe you can use it. Try it  and after installation, update and upgrade your ubuntu. 
You can install XBMC from Ubuntu software center that I did. But I suggest you can go on [this link](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=How-to:Install_XBMC_for_Linux) and pay attention to some tips there . And then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Some people have problems with XBMC on Ubuntu 14.04 X64. But I haven't had any after installing it and updating and upgrading Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know why but first I had a problem with XBMC. Nevertheless, after some days when my Ubuntu became up-to-date the problem was solved. And no error has been detected since that time. Besides I haven't had any problem with XBMC since that time. I think that all optional-add-ons with XMBC in Ubuntu software center must be selected first that I did. Then try to install XBMC.

I hope my solution will work for you too. 
So long!